# How to reference data stored at a System.Reflection.Pointer .Net object in matlab?

Tags: .net, matlab, image-processing

We are accessing a .NET object from matlab.  It's some image capture software, and we're wanting to copy the image data into matlab.

We have two options for getting at this data.  First is to create an image object which has in it's constructor an argument of type `unsigned char *` which when you look at the "limitations of .net" web page here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6-1.html#brpb58f-1
seems to indicate that you cannot pass a pointer to a .NET library in that fashion.  (EVen though we can create an appropriate pointer using the `libpointer` matlab function.

Second thought is that if we use a default constructor in this library, which under the hood manages the memory, and creates the buffer, the buffer is accessible via a System.Reflection.Pointer object. But, how do we grab the data from that pointer, and get it copied into a matlab array?

Cannot figure that out.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Speed for this step is not critical, so slow works for us.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be impossible to do, based upon out of band conversations with mathworks, and others.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a .NET wrapper library to cast the unmanaged array into a managed array that Matlab can access.

It seems that you might be using C++/CLI to create your .NET which allows you to use unmanaged array which might be why you are getting a reflexion pointer (I think if you were using C#, all of your arrays would be managed and visible from Matlab).

Simply create a new Class library under Visual Studio (ether C# or C++/CLI). Then add you .NET library as reference. Then write a static method that copy the array you want to access into a managed .NET array. Then Matlab will be able to see it, and you may simply convert it to Matlab using the uint8(dotNetArray) for example.

Alternatively, you can also modify your original .NET projet and write a method that copies the unmanaged array into a managed one. Assuming originalimgsize is an int containing your image size and originalimg is unsigned char *, in C++/CLI that would be something like

```
array<unsigned char> ^img = gcnew array<unsigned char>(originalimgsize); 
for (int i=0; i<originalimgsize; i++) 
    img[i] = originalimg[i];
```